# List all tables within DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show a list of all tables within my database

I have the below code:

```
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM vogaldes_fuse.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables ")or die('ERROR 315' );
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 echo "$num_rows";
```

However this does not show any results, instead i see `ERROR 315`

Also, I want to list the table names, how do I get these?

**UPDATE**
I have managed to get the correct number of tables using the below:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'vogaldes_fuse';")or die('ERROR 315' );
```

The last bit of my question still stand, how do I turn each table name into a string that I can then use to list in a `select` dropdown?

Comment: Try using `mysql_error` in your die to see what the error returned by mysql is. ([docs](http://php.net/mysql_error).)

Comment: What type of DB do you use? What error it produces?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh MYSQL database.

Comment: Just use `select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables` Remove `vogaldes_fuse.` database name

Comment: Also, I'm unsure that `vogaldes_fuse.` should be prepended. Ah, @Saty beat me to that one :P

Comment: What's wrong with `SHOW TABLES FROM dbname`?

Comment: I  have updated my question as managed to get the number of rows, now wanting to list them in a drop down (select)

Comment: @user3092953 another answer posted.And hope this will solve your problem .

Comment: @user3092953 check my answer below to create drop down of table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables` Remove `vogaldes_fuse.` database name

To create dropdown of table use

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'vogaldes_fuse'") or die('ERROR 315');
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {


        echo "<select name='table_name'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['TABLE_NAME'] . "'>" . $row['TABLE_NAME'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
```

**UPDATED**

For select `TABLE_SCHEMA` except some table

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'vogaldes_fuse' AND TABLE_NAME NOT 
IN ( 
'hr_employees', 'hr_roles' 
)
```

Comment: Thanks however the dropdown is not showing any table names?

Comment: Check updated answer. remove space between `TABLE_NAME` and `'`

Comment: Perfect... just to be pain, is there a way to say select all table except...? :)

Comment: `except` What ?? please elaborate!!

Comment: Except a table, for example select all tables except users

Comment: You can use `NOT IN(blab,blab)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113534/discussion-between-user3092953-and-saty).

Answer (score 0):

Run This

**USE 'your db name';
SHOW TABLES;**

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

Comment: I have updated my question as managed to get the number of rows, now wanting to list them in a drop down (select)

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM 'your db name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
echo "{$row[0]}</br>";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Hope this help .

Comment: Thanks, but i got this error
`DB Error, could not list tables MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''vogaldes_fuse'' at line 1`

Comment: SHOW TABLES FROM `your db name` ";

Comment: Thanks, can I select all tables except one?

Comment: You can try this <?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    if ($row[0] != 'my_private_table_name') {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
    }
}
?>

Answer (score -1):

For MySQL:

SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName'